# CentOS 6.8 PHP-FPM not working correctly with PHP CLI

Tags: php, centos6

I have spent the last day Googling this, and either my Google-Fu is having a bad day or no-one has asked this before.

These past couple of days I have been setting up a Vagrant VM with CentOS 6.8 for me to work on our website. I decided to install the same packages which are on our live server: Nginx, PHP-FPM & Percona. I removed PHP 5.3 and enabled 5.6 in the remi repo and currently have installed:

- php.x86_64 (5.6.25-1.el6.remi)
- php-cli.x86_64 (5.6.25-1.el6.remi)
- php-common.x86_64 (5.6.25-1.el6.remi)
- php-fpm.x86_64 (5.6.25-1.el6.remi)
- php-mbstring.x86_64 (5.6.25-1.el6.remi)
- php-mcrypt.x86_64 (5.6.25-1.el6.remi)
- php-mssql.x86_64 (5.6.25-1.el6.remi)
- php-mysqlnd.x86_64 (5.6.25-1.el6.remi)
- php-pdo.x86_64 (5.6.25-1.el6.remi)
- php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 (1.3.10-1.el6.remi.5.6)
- php-pecl-zip.x86_64 (1.13.4-1.el6.remi.5.6)
- php-xml.x86_64 (5.6.25-1.el6.remi)

Now at this point I was not aware of any issues as the website was running perfectly fine. However today I went to reindex the site, we are using Magento so I do it through CLI out of preference. The command is:

`php indexer.php reindexall`

All this outputed was:

```
Usage: php [-n] [-e] [-h] [-i] [-m] [-v] [-t] [-p ] [-g ] [-c ] [-d foo[=bar]] [-y ] [-D] [-F [-O]]
    -c | Look for php.ini file in this directory
    -n               No php.ini file will be used
    -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
    -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
    -h               This help
    -i               PHP information
    -m               Show compiled in modules
    -v               Version number
    -p, --prefix 
                   Specify alternative prefix path to FastCGI process manager (default: /usr).
    -g, --pid 
                   Specify the PID file location.
    -y, --fpm-config 
                   Specify alternative path to FastCGI process manager config file.
    -t, --test       Test FPM configuration and exit
    -D, --daemonize  force to run in background, and ignore daemonize option from config file
    -F, --nodaemonize
                   force to stay in foreground, and ignore daemonize option from config file
    -O, --force-stderr
                   force output to stderr in nodaemonize even if stderr is not a TTY
    -R, --allow-to-run-as-root
                   Allow pool to run as root (disabled by default)
```

I have never seen this happen. There were no errors in terminal or even in the log. I tried other php scripts I had and even created a really simple "hello world" test which I knew would run, but still got the same output. So I did some digging and after a while noticed my `php -v` showed `PHP 5.6.25 (fpm-fcgi)` instead of `PHP 5.6.25 (cli)`.

I tried removing the php-fpm package, which then fixed the output of `php -v`, and enabled my simple test script to run, however that's not really a fix as that leaves me without php-fpm.

I really hope this is just a simple setting I have missed as it obviously works fine on our live server. I did ask our host support and they haven't seen it before either.

So, after all that background, I suppose the short question is how to install php-fpm without it conflicting with php-cli?

Comment: when you want to see where an alias (softlink) points to, use like that: `which php` I guess the output is like `/usr/bin/php5-fpm` - which is the wrong SAPI binary for client/console use.

Comment: @DanFromGermany it outputs as `/usr/sbin/php`, but if I do `/usr/bin/php` and the command it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the full path to the desired PHP executable. Something like:

`/usr/bin/php indexer.php reindexall`

Comment: Thank you! That made the script run. I had tried `/usr/sbin/php` as that's what `which php` gave me, but didn't think of `/usr/bin/php`. Is there a way to make it work with just using `php`? If you could point me in a direction I'll see what I can find in Google first, but if not I suppose I could always just use an alias.

Comment: /usr/sbin would normally only be accesible to root. What do you see if you type `ls -l /usr/sbin/php` ? If it's only a symlink, then I think you can safely unlink and then relink with `ln -s /usr/bin/php /usr/sbin/php`  That way, all your previous CLI calls should still work!

Comment: this is what I get: `lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Aug 24 16:05 /usr/sbin/php -> /usr/sbin/php-fpm`, should it still be safe to relink?

Comment: You might need to use `chmod 777 /usr/sbin/php` after creating the symlink. I'm not certain if this will work, because I think it's strange that php-fpm is installed in `/usr/sbin/` with 777 privileges. If anything breaks, you can always relink back to `/usr/sbin/php-fpm. ` followed by another `chmod 777 /usr/sbin/php` to get back to the old situation.

Comment: Ben, you're a legend, thank you. Unlinking it and doing `ln -s /usr/bin/php /usr/sbin/php` worked fine. I did `chmod 777 /usr/sbin/php` and `service php-fpm restart` just in case. `php -v` now shows `PHP 5.6.25 (cli)` and the site is still working fine

Comment: Excellent. You might want to use phpinfo (http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) somewhere in your site to check its running the PHP version you think it is, but it sounds like you're good!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where you /usr/sbin/php comes from

```
# rpm -q php-cli php-fpm
php-cli-5.6.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-fpm-5.6.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64

# which php
/usr/bin/php

# php -v
PHP 5.6.25 (cli) (built: Aug 31 2016 19:26:19) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

# rpm -qf /usr/sbin/php
error: file /usr/sbin/php: No such file or directory
```

So you can probably just remove it.